# jQuery - if statement with 2 conditions adds a class when both condition are passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am attempting to write an if statement with 2 conditions.

Condition one is to see if `<time>` has the class `class="overdue"`.

The second condition would be to see if both the datetime inside the `<div>` and the datetime inside the `<a>` match.

When both condition one and condition two are met the result would be that the `<a>` tag would be given the red class but only if both conditions have been met.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qk79jgL4/

**HTML**

```
<div><time class="overdue" datetime="2013-03-10">March 10th, 2013</time></div>
<div><time datetime="2013-03-11">March 11th, 2013</time></div>
<a href="#" class="cal-evt"><time datetime="2013-03-10">10</time></a>
<a href="#" class="cal-evt"><time datetime="2013-03-11">11</time></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($("time").hasClass("overdue")) {

    $("a.cal-evt").addClass("red");

}

return false;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an `&&` which would read as "and". EG `if (predicate1 && predicate2) { doSomething() }`

Comment: *" if both the datetime inside the `<div>` and the datetime inside the `<a>` match"* - there are 2 `<div>`'s and 2 `<a>`'s can you be more specific..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the traversing methods of jquery and use them to target the elements you want

```
$("time.overdue").each(function(){  // for each time that has overdue class
    var time = $(this).attr('datetime'); // store its datetime value

    $("a.cal-evt").filter(function(){ // find all the cal-evt links that contain the same time
        return $('time', this).attr('datetime') == time;
    }).addClass("red"); // apply the red class on the filtered items

});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qk79jgL4/9/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Very solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, in place of an `if`, simply using, at the appropriate time:

```
// find the element with a datetime attribute within an a element of
// class 'cal-evt', filter that collection:
$('a.cal-evt [datetime]').filter(function(){
    // keeping only those whose datetime attribute is equal to the datetime attribute
    // of the (first) 'time.overdue' element:
    return this.getAttribute('datetime') == $('time.overdue').attr('datetime');
// find the closest ancestor a element, and add the class 'red' to it:
}).closest('a').addClass('red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qk79jgL4/14/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation).
- JavaScript

  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the code should function even if there are multiple time tags with the class overdue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$( "time" ).filter( "[datetime='" + $( 'time.overdue' ).attr( 'datetime' ) + "']" ).parent( 'a' ).addClass("red");
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qk79jgL4/13/)**

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the code should function even if there are multiple time tags with the class overdue

Answer (score -1):

```
$("time").each(function() {
if($(this).hasClass("overdue")){
    var mydate = $(this).attr("dateTime");

    $(".cal-evt").each(function() {            
        if($(this).find("time").attr("dateTime")==mydate){
              $(this).addClass("red");
        }
    });
}
});
return false;
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qk79jgL4/15/

and who ever downvoted it, why?  It works as asked.